# Using List Comprehensions to create multiple SubList in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
list1 = [0,2,4,6]
```

Here I want to add number  2 to the list1 and create a sublist in new list , and create another sublist using the first sublist to create new sublist .
I want to create a new list from list1  with the help of list comprehentions only  and that too in single line .

```
newList = [[2,4,6,8],[4,6,8,10],[6,8,10,12]]
```

For example :

```
newList = [a+2 for a in list1]
```

but with this code I am able to create only 1 list inside newList.but I want to create 3 sublist accordingly in newList using list Comprehensions only.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? You have tagged both

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
list1 = [0,2,5,6]
```

you can create 3 lists inside a list using 2 nested list comprehensions:

```
newlist = [[x+2*(i+1) for x in list1] for i in range(3)]
```

the result

```
[[2, 4, 7, 8], [4, 6, 9, 10], [6, 8, 11, 12]]
```

is different from the one in the question, but Jim edited it in the meanwhile (for correctness), and I personally prefer that the input list has no internal logic (else we could be tempted to only use `range` to solve that).

Note that we can do it with list comprehension only because we can deduce the sublists from the initial input list. It's not possible in general to compute current element from previous one using list comprehension. You have to switch to a "classical" `for` loop in that case.

Comment: What I'm guessing is that the OP made a mistake in the original list. It looks like it's supposed to be `[0, 2, 4, 6]`

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard yes. But I prefer an "irregular" input, else there's no need for an input list.